# spark-shell commands throwing error : “error: not found: value spark”

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuR4Q.png)

:14: error: not found: value spark
import spark.implicits._
^
:14: error: not found: value spark
import spark.sql
^

here is my enviroment configuration. I different many times but I keep getting this error. Anyone knows the reason? I saw a similar question but the answers did not solve my problem.

JAVA_HOME   : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51

HADOOP_HOME : C:\Hadoop\winutils-master\hadoop-2.7.1

SPARK_HOME  : C:\Hadoop\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

PATH :%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SCALA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;

Comment: The versions in your screenshots are different than what you think. I'll start with that.

Comment: Also don't post screenshots, rather paste the code / output in the question in a formatted form